# Express.Static not working for subdirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Express.static is working great for any view in root directory, but it breaks when I add a subdirectory.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Works:

```
//Homepage
router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index.hbs', {user: req.user, message:req.flash('message')});      //add add'l data {title:'Express', addlData:'SomeData', layout:'layout'}
});
```

Doesn't Work:

```
//Organization Profile
router.get('/orgprofile/:username', function(req,res,next){
    User.findOne({username:req.params.username}, function(err,docs){
        res.render('orgprofile.hbs',{orgdetails:docs});
    });
});
```

I'm guessing __dirname is changed to whatever directory the `get` request is made from, but I just want to use the root (/public) directory for all static requests.

Comment: `__dirname` is not changed per request.  To resolve this, please show the URL you wish to be served as a static request and the directory structure where you want the static request to come from.  And, also, `express.static()` has nothing to do with `res.render()` calls if that is what your problem is.  Those are normal file operations that go through the template layout engine, not through the middleware code path where `express.static()` is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/orgprofile', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it basically saying "replace '/orgprofile' with (__dirname + '/public')"  ?

Comment: Yes, its setting all the request coming on the handle to be served from the directory.

Comment: Downvoted because you have to manually create routes for every subfolder you have.

Comment: Hey @WonderDog, the answer is based on the limits by express. I understand that this is not a great solution. Might be better to open a feature request with Express than downvoting the only existing solution.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is not caused by express.static() expression. It might be due to wrong  href value.
express.static():

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Reference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
```

Comment: This is a better approach than the accepted answer. Try not to repeat yourself

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If I use an URL like http://localhost:8080/postcreate/personal it would fail because of wrong value of `__dirname`. The URLs in the layout file for `css`,  `js` files or `image` sources get the wrong prefix. I did solve this by using: `proces.env.PWD` instead. Now its always using the project folder and that's what I want. The project folder is my `root`. Same like `.NET` projects work. The problem with me was that I set express.static in a seperate app folder.